# How to Deserialise Json String which contain Chinese characters in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a problem while deserialise Json string into object which is contain chinese or russian characters in one of the field.If we are using the normal json Deserialiser the particular field becomes empty can you please any one help me on this

My Json String has a format as follows

```
{  
    "SportsAppId":"",
    "SportId":"",
    "Version":0,
    "Url":"",
    "Image":"",
    "Description":"",
    "AdditionalType":"",
    "Name":"微软",
    "SatoriId":"",
    "LastUpdatedAt":0
}
```

And i used Newtonsoft.Json

and my deserialisation code as

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
```

Comment: Works fine for me: 
`string data = "{\"Name\":\"微软\"}";

dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

string name = d.Name;`

Comment: You included JSON data with Chinese characters in your question. Is that the actual data that is also in your local variable `data` before calling `DeserializeObject`? In other words, does that still contain those Chinese characters? (If you didn't specifically check, please do check.)

Comment: [Also works fine for me.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wqn3V0) Perhaps you can provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deserialize with culture format

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings() 
{ Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("zh-CHT")  });
```

Comment: still getting same output ie.. name is missing

Comment: the object having the value but while reading that value it gives empty result

Comment: try to change current culture of project